# ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Tags: asp-classic

I'm getting an error in my .asp file, and I don't know how to solve this (I don't know ASP, it's an old project of my client, other developer did this).
The error what i'm getting is the following:

```
    ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

    Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

    /br/grava_cadastro.asp, line 105
```

And the lines:

```
 100 %>
 101   <!--#include file="abrir_arquivo.asp"-->  
 102 <%
 103 xip= Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
 104 RS.Open "SELECT * from  visitas where vi_data = date() and vi_ip='" &  xip & "'",cn,3,3
 105 xlink=rs("vi_link")
 106 rs.close
```

It's blocking my signup form. Somebody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Why do I get 'BOF or EOF' errors?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-bof-or-eof-errors.html)

Comment: Before I ask this here, I have searched and don't understand... my code are different of the example, and how I've sayed, I don't know anything about asp... :(

Comment: Why have you tagged this `asp.net`, when it looks to me like `asp-classic`?

Comment: omg...(I don't know anything about asp) [3]

Comment: Resolved error '800a0bcd'... Just Allow cookies...through internet explorer settings.It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that you have records?

in `line 105` you are asumming that the is a record,  what if not?

why don't you add something like this:

```
   if rs.eof = false then
       xlink=rs("vi_link")
   end if
```

also,

in the sql line you have this:

```
RS.Open "SELECT * from  visitas where vi_data = date() and vi_ip='" &  xip & "'",cn,3,3
```

but I am not sure if `date()` should go like that,   it should have `'"& date() &"'  or "& date() &"` (not remember if date is considered string or numeric)

it should be like this:

```
RS.Open "SELECT * from  visitas where vi_data = '" & date() & "' and vi_ip='" &  xip & "'",cn,3,3
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro. I changed the line 105 (if rs.eof = false then xlink=rs("vi_link") end if) and it worked! Did not have to change the line of SQL. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We received this error on a legacy Classic ASP application. It turned out a value they were copying from another system into the submission form was adding non-visible characters to the input field.