# ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bcd' Classic ASP

Tags: html, mysql, oracle, asp-classic

ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bcd'

Either `BOF` or `EOF` is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

> **/login/reset_form.asp, line 8. Line 8 is rs.MoveFirst**

```vbs
DIM mySQL, objRS, rs
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM medacist_user WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "'"
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objRS.Open  "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Data Source=****"
Set rs = objRS.Execute(mySQL)

rs.MoveFirst
rs("Password") = Request.Form("Password")
rs("DateLastUpdated") = Date()
rs.Update

objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing

Response.Write "<div align='center'>" & strUsername & ",<br>"
Response.Write " Your password has been succesffully updated in our database.<br><br>"

objRS.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
objCONN.Close
Set objCONN = Nothing
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648119/adodb-field-error-800a0bcd

Comment: In this case [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=800a0bcd+Classic+ASP&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=800a0bcd+classic+asp&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=7081ad9f532242f3b8932f2aae5af35b) is your friend. It took me a couple of seconds to type your problem into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating a record you don't need a recordset because you don't need to display any data. Just use an update query, eg

```
mySQL = "UPDATE medacist_user set Password = "& Request.Form("Password") &", Date = "& Date() & " WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "'"
objRS.Execute(mySQL)
```

If you haven't done so already, you'll need to think about preventing two or more users from having the same username